# Example of External Identity Provider with openiddict

Tags: openiddict

Hi  I'm new to web security, so please be gentle :)

I've been reading a huge amount about OAuth2/OIDC, JWT, openiddict, ASP.NET Core Identity, etc, but I keep going around in circles trying to understand how multiple-external id providers is supposed to work.

I'm looking to create an SPA application (React) with ASP.NET Core web api (I am primarlily a C# developer.)

Any examples on how to do the google/social login with openiddict issuing the auth&id tokens to my client would be great. (I know I'm supposed to use auth code+PKCE for SPA security - no client secret involved, etc.)

I'd like to offer signup/sign-in via user/pwd or any of the major social external provider (Gooble, Facebook, Twitter.)

Does opennidd even support this? i.e. multipe identity providers?  If so, I can't see how to get it to return the required token, once the google oidc process has returned the tokens to me.

Many thanks.